# jQuery wResize - resizing IE windows

Tags: html, jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, jquery-events

I have encountered a problem with re-sizing IE windows.

I have considered using a timeout event, but this isn't good enough because time may vary from one re-size to another and I'm not interested to setting a time-out to 5+ seconds.

Are you aware of any alternatives to wResize jQuery plugin?

The problem is IE firing the re-size event each time it encounters a slight change in X or Y coordinates in any element on the page. Each time I re-size the page I can see a very obvious repetitive rendering taking place on the page, E.g. div appears and disappears up to 10 times depending on how much time the user spent re-sizing a page.

Comment: You never said what the problem was....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implemented with timers. The jQuery wresize plugin didn't really work.